# retrieving classified distribution artifacts from nexus

Tags: maven-2, distribution, nexus

I would like to provide platform specific distributions of my complex multi module project using the maven-assembly-plugin. I have a top level distribution that includes multiple lower level distributions some of which are platform specific and are included accordingly. Building with maven 2.2.1 for the different platforms works fine however retrieving the different versions from nexus (version 1.9.0.1) after deploying them is not possible (I found references to this problem elsewhere but not in the context of assemblies). I can only ever retrieve the last one build.

Let's say I have distribution for linux and win. I have two hudson jobs one for each distribution at the end of which the zips are deployed to nexus. The problem that I face is that I can find both versions in my nexus UI after they have been build (looking in the file system both expected zip files are also there) but the nexus metadata points to the one that was build last (I use uniqueIdentifiers). So while I can find both my distribution-win and distribution-linux in my nexus UI, I can only download the last one. Is this a bug in nexus or is my usage of classifiers in this scenario incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the spam, I fixed the problem by turning of the unique versions.